# can excel vba (function or Sub) return List of Data For "Data Validation >> List >> Source"?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, ms-access

can excel vba (function or Sub) return List of Data For "Data Validation >> List >> Source" ?
Data Validation List (Drop Down List / combo Box) data source from my vba code Like:

```
= MyFunction()
return Like:
Apple,
Tool,Bag,Everything ...
```

more details:
I need to search something with  multi condition

```
Function myFunction(Rng1 As Range)
txtSearch As String
txtSearch = Rng1.Text
' do somting 

' return
' aApple,Tool,Bag,Everything ...
End Function
```

thanks for advice.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614859/4717755) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60514105/4717755)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try using the next function:

```
Function extractValidationList(vCell As Range) As String
    Dim strFormula As String
    
     strFormula = vCell.Validation.Formula1
        
     If left(strFormula, 1) = "=" Then
        Dim inputRange As Range, c As Range
        Set inputRange = Evaluate(strFormula)
        If inputRange.rows.count > inputRange.Columns.count Then
            'extract a 1D array from a range with more rows and one column and Join it
            extractValidationList = Join(Application.Transpose(inputRange.value), ", ")
        ElseIf inputRange.Columns.count > inputRange.rows.count Then
            'extract a 1D array from a range with more columns and one row and Join it
            extractValidationList = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(inputRange.value)), ", ")
        End If
    Else
        Dim arrF, listSep As String
        listSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
        arrF = Split(strFormula, listSep)
        extractValidationList = Join(arrF, ", ")
    End If
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next `Sub`:

```
Sub testExtractValidationList()
   Debug.Print extractValidationList(ActiveCell) 'previously select the validated cell...
End Sub
```

Or using it UDF (User Defined Function), writing a formula in a cell:

```
=extractValidationList(C6)
```

where, C6 is the list validated cell, where from to extract the list...

Comment: @abdol-hamid Hosseiny Didn't you fins some time to test the above function? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: thanks for replay, but isn't Answer. Data > Data Tools > Data Validation > List > Source> = MyFunction()

Comment: I cannot get you... MyFunction(), without an argument will raise an error. You should try it as "=MyFunction(C6)". It can be also done in code. I thought this is something elementary and only supplied the function able to extract the list from any list validation type...